# Can a field have XmlAttribute and XmlElement attributes?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I need to read/write a xml element in any of the following ways.

```
<element param="..." set="...">
</element>

<element>
 <param>...</param>
 <set>...</set>
</element>

<element param="...">
 <set>...</set>
</element>

<element set="...">
 <param>...</param>
</element>
```

Is it possible to have a class with this form to do the work?

```c#
[XmlType("element")]
public class Element
{
  [XmlAttribute, XmlElement]
  public string param { get; set; }
  [XmlAttribute, XmlElement]
  public string set { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It strikes me that it shouldn't take you long to test this yourself...

Comment: Also this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133429/deserializing-xml-in-c-sharp-where-a-property-could-be-either-an-attribute-or-an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a XML class which can have Element and Attribute with the same name like this one?

```
    [XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "element")]
    public class ElementRoot
    {
        [XmlAttribute("param")]
        public string paramAtribute;

        [XmlElement("param")]
        public string paramElement;

        [XmlAttribute("set")]
        public string setAtribute;

        [XmlElement("set")]
        public string setElement;
    }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" param="..." set="...">
   <param>...</param>
   <set>...</set>
</element>
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfect. Well, I expected to have a way that is shorter.